# importing schema from file causes ReferenceError: Cannot access 'MySchema' before initialization

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, mongoose-schema

I have a schema that I export from a file

```js
// Vendor.ts

export { ShortVendorSchema };

const ShortVendorSchema = new Schema<TShortVendor>({
    defaultVendor: Boolean,
    companyName: String,
    vendorId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Vendor' },
});
```

and import it to another schema

```js
// Order.ts
import { ShortVendorSchema } from './Vendor';

const OrderSchema = new Schema<TOrderSchema>(
    {
        status: {
            type: String,
            enum: Object.keys(ORDER_STATUS),
            default: 'NEW',
        },
        vendor: ShortVendorSchema,
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

Whenever I'm trying to access `Order` model I get error `error - ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ShortVendorSchema' before initialization`

I have an idea why it happens, something about api routes living in isolation, but I don't know how to solve it without duplicating `ShortVendorSchema` in all files where it's used.

**upd**: moved all model exports into a single file, now I'm getting error `error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ShortVendorSchema')`

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using `const` to declare a variable and variables defined using `const` and `let` are not hoisted, meaning they are not reachable before declaring. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting. You should always declare variables before exporting or using them.

Comment: @shubham you sure? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#description

Comment: That is just an example of two types of exports. Can you ask more about the needed surity?

Comment: You can simply export `ShortVendorSchema` as `export const ShortVendorSchema = new Schema<TShortVendor>({ ... })`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because of circular dependency.

I was importing `ShortVendorSchema` to `Order.ts` file and `OrderSchema` to `Vendor.ts` file.

The solution is to move `ShortVendorSchema` to a separate file that doesn't have any imports.